# time difference between two same tweet

Tags: r, twitter, dataframe

How to calculate time difference between two same tweet(from text perspective) and add a column in data frame to show that time difference timediff(new column name ) td3 = t3-t2.   td13 = t13-t12 if t13 and t12 both are same text/tweet.

Input DATA

Tweet Text                               TIME-Stamp

rt aamaadmiparty arvindkejriwal leaves   2014-03-24 17:18:53
rt aamaadmiparty arvindkejriwal leaves   2014-03-24 22:37:11
rt aamaadmiparty arvindkejriwal leaves   2014-03-24 22:44:51
rt aamaadmiparty arvindkejriwal leaves   2014-03-25 13:24:31
rt aamaadmiparty download the aap        2014-03-25 19:31:06
rt aamaadmiparty download the aap        2014-03-25 19:34:29
rt aamaadmiparty download the aap        2014-03-25 19:42:10
rt aamaadmiparty download the aap        2014-03-25 19:53:38

Desired OutPut Data

**Tweet Text**                          **TIME-Stamp**           **T-Diff**

rt aamaadmiparty arvindkejriwal leaves    2014-03-24 17:18:53  **0**
rt aamaadmiparty arvindkejriwal leaves    2014-03-24 22:37:11  **5.305 hours** 
rt aamaadmiparty arvindkejriwal leaves    2014-03-24 22:44:51  **5.432778 hours**

rt aamaadmiparty download the aap         2014-03-25 19:31:06  **0**
rt aamaadmiparty download the aap         2014-03-25 19:34:29  **3.383333 mins**
rt aamaadmiparty download the aap         2014-03-25 19:42:10  **11.06667 mins**
rt aamaadmiparty download the aap         2014-03-25 23:36:57  **4.0975 hours**

this code is working but how to add it in column using loop for large dataset is not clear to me ....
df is the working dataframe ..

> difftime(df[49,2],df[48,2])
>   Time difference of 3.383333 mins
>   difftime(df[51,2],df[48,2])
>   Time difference of 11.06667 mins
>   df$diff_time<-(difftime(df[65,2],df[48,2]))
>   difftime(df[65,2],df[48,2])
>   Time difference of 4.0975 hours

Comment: Please provide sample data, also show some effort.

Comment: Sir i updated my query with details example...please help me @ zx8754

Answer (score 0):

an illustration

```
# toy data
time_1 = strptime("3/22/2014 15:08", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
time_2 = strptime("3/22/2014 15:15", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
ID = "user_1"
df = data.frame(ID, time_1, time_2)

#       ID              time_1              time_2
# 1 user_1 2014-03-22 15:08:00 2014-03-22 15:15:00

# by base R
df$diff_time <- with(df, time_2 - time_1)
# by dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(diff_time = time_2 - time_1)

# you get
#       ID              time_1              time_2 diff_time
# 1 user_1 2014-03-22 15:08:00 2014-03-22 15:15:00    7 mins
```